# <f:convertNumber number pattern for displaying "10000000" as "1,00,00,000" - JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have a h:outputText field, which is used to display amounts in a specific pattern.

Eg. 10000000 needs to be formatted as 1,00,00,000
I used `<f:convertNumber />` tag for achieving this. I tried by adding hi_IN & en_IN in locale attribute, but the result is getting formatted as 10,000,000. Then tried by applying the pattern attribute with the following value(#,##,##0.00) got the same result 10,000,000.00. Kindly suggest?

Sample Code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{sampleBean.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##,##0.00"/>
</h:outputText>

<h:outputText value="#{sampleBean.amount}">
   <f:convertNumber locale="hi_IN" />
</h:outputText>

<h:outputText value="#{sampleBean.amount}">
   <f:convertNumber locale="en_IN" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make Custom Converter as follow,

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("currencyFormat")
public class CurrencyFormat implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if (value.toString().trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Locale l=new Locale("en", "in");
            NumberFormat format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(l);
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            return format.format(new BigDecimal(value.toString()));

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid Number"));
        }
    }
}}
```

Then Try following,

```
<h:outputText value="10000000" converter="currencyFormat"/>
```

**Note:** I've used [IBM icu4j library](http://site.icu-project.org/download) to convert number, which is available [at here](http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4j/49.1/icu4j-49_1.jar)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for currencies, you can take a look at the `<f:convertNumber />` with the `type="currency"`. You will be able to display the amount according to the locale. You can also override the current locale using `locale="YourLocale"`.

Of course for more custom purposes, @Jitesh answer is perfect.